# React-Native Navigation Bar custom viewport button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, viewport

How would I go about putting a button that opens up a viewport inside the navigation bar that is a route for different screens?

For example (the post button opens up a viewport and the other buttons route to different screens:[image: Linkedin Mobile Screen]

I am trying to put a viewport open button inside a navigation bar

Comment: `opens up a viewport` You mean you want to open a modal, right?